# In Word 2010, how do I duplicate two rows in a table and preserve their formatting?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have the following table in Word:

[image: original table]

I'd like to duplicate the last two rows to make another use case. There are many ways to do this, but all that I've tried end up with unsatisfactory results. I start by selecting and copying the last two rows:

## Place the cursor to the right of the last row and paste

[image]
That adds a blank row to the bottom of the table and places the copied rows in a new column to the right. It also removes the formatting from the header row. Odd.

## Place the cursor below the table and paste

[image]
That almost does the trick. It appends the two rows to the table, retains some of the formatting (the background) but removes the formatting of the text in the header cell (bold, centered). It also increases the height of the header row. Really odd.

## Append a new row, place the cursor in it, and paste

[image]
That's very close. Now we get both rows. The header cell height is correct, the text formatting within it is correct, but the cell background has disappeared. Strange.

## Place the cursor below the table and paste. Then choose "Keep Original Table Formatting."

[image]
Now the text formatting is correct, the cell background is there, but the new rows are shorter than the original ones. Really strange.

Comment: I cannot fully reproduce this behaviour. I see background disappearing when pasting just below table, but I don't see short rows or height changes. Anyway - how about pasting those two rows not in the first line below original table but in the second line and then removing the first line? Works for me (as some of your solutions).